# Automatically starting application as background process when the OS boots in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, database, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on RFID based database project where the RFidReader read the RFTag number stored in the Tag memory and sent it to the computer for checking in the that number on the data base database.  I have wrote both the hardware side coding and data base side coding. but now I am stuck to write the middle interface that starts automatically(No manual interference) When operation system boots and fetch records(TagIds) from the database, store that record in array and apply binary search for the upcoming Tagid from the outside environment(RFidReader), the interface must be background process.can any body tell me how to achieve this in C#?

Comment: So you're building a background RFID sniffer? Sounds kind of shady.

Comment: You can implement it as a Windows service: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ChrisW. kinda like that.... but this is a security checking system  would be install on the man entrance gate of my university..

Comment: Oooh so you're not just collecting, I gotcha now. Sorry

Comment: @ChrisW. can you please suggest some way?